# Delete from multiple tables using temp table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm previewing the data I'm about to delete, but this SQL looks a little redundant.  Is there a better way to write this?

```
declare @history table(pid int)
insert into @history select pid from plans p where p.pidSynergy = 'P0022' and p.pid != 2885

select * from forecast_FTEs where pid in (select pid from @history)
select * from forecast_phases where pid in (select pid from @history)
select * from budget_FTEs where pid in (select pid from @history)
select * from budget_phases where pid in (select pid from @history)
select * from plans where pid in (select pid from @history)
```

Comment: You should add a primary key to the table variable and only insert distinct not null values. Also consider using `recompile` so it takes account of correct table variable cardinality.

Comment: Also consider habitually using two part naming for the column referenced in the inner part of the `in` to avoid this type of error. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4594733/sql-server-2008-management-studio-not-checking-the-syntax-of-my-query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Not really.**

- `LEFT JOIN` returns an exponential amount of records, so is no good for `SELECT`. (540540 records in my case, 378378 after deleting 10 records of one table, saving 20 of 70 seconds)
- `INNER JOIN` also leaves out incomplete entries. (360360 records in 48 seconds)
- `IN (a, b, c)` [is the same as `OR`, and is only efficient up to 64 items](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/0272328c-e2b2-43d7-98e3-68dd50bfd6a0/in-where-clasueusing-in-or-orwhich-is-betterespecially-when-query-governor-cost-limit-is). The maximum number of values is [limited by memory and time](http://bytes.com/topic/sql-server/answers/143498-clause-limitation).
- That leaves [string hacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-a-sql-in-clause), which is also limited by length and might add character escaping problems.

`TABLE` is the only way to store an array in TSQL, so `WHERE column IN (SELECT column FROM @table_var)` is the shortest generic way to match a set of values.

Comment: In can handle more than 64 items. Though long in lists should generally be avoided.

Comment: Good catch, I did not realize my query would return a cartesian product. I went and marked my answer as deleted since it is wrong.

Answer (score 3):

`p` is a cryptic table alias and that `!=` is not ANSI compliant, you should try and use `<>` instead. Also, the `select * from` is inefficient because it has to go back to the information schema and look up every column, you should try and only select the columns you really need.

Comment: Beat me to it. Welcome to Code Review.

Comment: Thanks for the tips, but as this is an uncommon and manual action, i'm more interested in shorter code, perhaps by somehow creating an array of pids so i can just type `where pid in pids`.

Comment: The reasoning for avoiding `*` is bogus. It would have to validate column metadata anyway. Whilst generally `*` should be avoided in production queries I wouldn't worry about it in adhoc interactive queries as described in the OP. Except if the table contains wide columns.